# Is there an API to query for the maximum number of connected devices supported by the BLE master?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an app where it's possible to connect to multiple BLE peripherals. My experience is that there is a limit where things don't really work (no clear errors though), and it seems to be device-specific according to other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154919/how-many-devices-we-can-pair-via-bluetooth-of-ble-to-android) on this topic.

> The BLE standard does not really define the maximum number of devices (see here), but using the BLE-Stack (starting from v1.1) the master shall support up to 3 simultaneous connections.
>
> [Source (Texas Instruments)](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/BLE_-_FAQ#How_many_slave_devices_can_be_connected_to_a_BLE_master_simultaneously.3F)

Given that TI is right about this and that the limitation is BLE chip-specific, is there a way to ask the device itself (through the Android API) about its limitations? I want my app to detect that the limit has been reached and act on this information.