# Android Bluetooth Low Energy Characteristic notification count limit: does this vary by device?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

#### Context

I am building an Android app targeting 5.0+ that uses BLE to connect to multiple peripherals. Each of these peripherals has many (~10) characteristics. Ideally, I would like to subscribe to notifications of changes for every single one of these characteristics.

However, my understanding from reading around is that Android's Bluetooth implementations enforce a hard limit on the number of simultaneous notifications that can be active. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37756809/2911458) identifies where the limit is defined within the Android Bluetooth [implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/master/bta/gatt/bta_gattc_int.h#345), and also notes how the limit has changed over time:

> Max concurrent active notifications (`BTA_GATTC_NOTIF_REG_MAX`):
>
> - 4 on Android 4.3
> - 7 on Android 4.4
> - 15 on Android 5.0+

These numbers are confirmed by Dave Smith in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qx55Sa8UZAQ&t=28m06s) where it is also suggested that:

- these limits are global to the device (i.e. if some other app is subscribed to 2 notifications, the number available to my app is reduced by 2);
- these limits should not vary based on anything other than Android OS level (i.e. they should be independent of manufacturer, actual hardware capabilities, etc.)

#### Problem

In testing on 5.0+ devices, however, I have found that I am apparently able to successfully subscribe to **more** than 15 notifications. So far I have observed this on:

- Pixel XL running 7.1.1
- Galaxy S6 running 6.0.1
- Nexus 5 running 5.X

These notification subscriptions are successful by two measures:

1. The GATT operation status is a `GATT_SUCCESS`;
2. The app is able to receive notifications on characteristic changes from all target characteristics.

This is mixed news. On the one hand, more "real" notifications ==> less manual polling ==> better user experience. On the other hand, being unable to create conditions that cause "real" notification setup to fail means I can't easily write or test the manual fallback code that will surely(?) be required once this app is released to real users.

#### Questions

- Is this limit-ignoring behavior expected? (I have not been able to find it described elsewhere.)
- Are there any devices known to max out at exactly 15 notifications that I can use to test the unhappy path?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The APIs are quite badly designed. Just the fact that this implementation uses a fixed size array rather than a dynamic array is probably a legacy from when the library was written in C.

The internal C++ library actually [returns an error](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/221e9bf6c9e9f974efd92ea4f054dbdba248d2db/bta/gatt/bta_gattc_api.cc#625) when it fails to allocate a notification entry. Unfortunately that error is only logged and is not propagated to the Java layer of the consuming application ([source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/3ae219d81403f905ed4efc3b6071acae075e7660/src/com/android/bluetooth/gatt/GattService.java#935)). This means that developers have no way to determine (in code) when they hit the limit.

Anyway, the `BTA_GATTC_NOTIF_REG_MAX` limit is per `BluetoothGatt` object, so if another app is connected it should not interfere with your notification registrations. You can even have two `BluetoothGatt` objects in the same app connecting to the same device, and that way get double as many notification registration slots.

The max number of slots is defined [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/221e9bf6c9e9f974efd92ea4f054dbdba248d2db/bta/gatt/bta_gattc_int.h#260). It's incorrect that OS level is the only thing that defines this value, as manufacturers are free to change this value. For example I know that Samsung has in some of their devices increased the maximum number of connections (that is otherwise hardcoded to 7), so they might also have increased this value.

I can't explain how you succeeded in subscribing to more than 15 notifications on the Google phones. Did you configure more than 15 notifications on a single device or over many devices?

Comment: Thanks, great answer with a ton of useful information! In particular, I believe the assertion "the `BTA_GATTC_NOTIF_REG_MAX` limit is per `BluetoothGatt` object" explains why I was confused about not hitting said limit in practice - I previously thought the limit applied to all `BluetoothGatt` objects _combined_, rather than to each `BluetoothGatt` object individually.

Comment: Per Dave Smith: ["The code isn’t the easiest to interpret, but the limit is applied per “client interface”.](https://twitter.com/devunwired/status/841489232136925186) [It’s not entirely clear if a “client” is an app or a GATT callback. It’s most likely the latter, though."](https://twitter.com/devunwired/status/841489489633652740) This is consistent with your comments!

Comment: "You can even have two `BluetoothGatt` objects in the same app connecting to the same device, and that way get double as many notification registration slots." seems like a good trick to be aware of also.

Comment: Beware though of the limit of the maximum BluetoothGatt objects, which in current Android verison is 32 globally. Probably less due to internal usage.

Comment: Also good to know - luckily I don't think I'll be pushing up against _that_ limit this time around! Do you know where the value 32 is set?

Comment: Yes. It's set here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/f6d79c5d6c9cc829dcfa033d59bade4d83334df7/include/bt_target.h#737

Comment: >The APIs are quite badly designed.

Preach!