# How many device can connect using Bluetooth tethering

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

How many device is able to connect to bluetooth tethering using an android phone? My android only allows up to 10 connection in mobile hotspot. How about in bluetooth tethering?

Comment: If I remember correctly, bluetooth can be attached to one device per time. So tethering cab be work only for one device per time

Comment: @SyoritoHatsuki i already tried 3 android device connected to my bluetooth tethering,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For classic Bluetooth, there isn't any limit imposed at the OS level and this limitation is usually dictated at the hardware level. In other words the limitation will vary from one Android device to another and unfortunately this information is not usually shared. Have a look at the following links for more info:-

- [How many devices can we pair via Bluetooth in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154919/how-many-devices-we-can-pair-via-bluetooth-of-ble-to-android)
- [How many Bluetooth devices can communicate with an Android device at the same time](https://qr.ae/pGxynb)